# CMS page is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

I have added one new CMS page. Its redirecting to homepage if preview clicked. I have also checked with default `about-us` page but still its redirecting to homepage.

It should redirect to `404 Page` if the page is not there but its redirecting to homepage. I have checked in `System->Configuration->web->default page` also. 404 Not found only selected for CMS no route page option.

Can anyone tell me why it is happening?

Comment: clear cache will work

Comment: I have cleared many times but still its not working @BornCoder

Comment: Problem solved by Opening app/code/community/Manthan/Marketplace/Controller/Router.php and then removing this first argument 'count($path >2)' from if condition .thats it.

Comment: open about us page manually with index.php